# Accessing NPM repository through a proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, npm

I'm trying to access the npm repository from an intranet using a proxy.

Using the proxy (set in the environment variables HTTP_Proxy and HTTPS_Proxy) I'm able to access the repository without ssl using my browser, and using wget:

```
wget registry.npmjs.org/yuidocjs
```

When I use https, I can access with my browser, but not with wget

```
wget https://registry.npm.js.org/yuidocjs #fails
```

When I try to use NPM, setting `registry=http://registry.npm.js.org/` results in a 404.

When I use the default https registry path, it results in a timeout.

Anything I'm missing here?  My config file looks like this:

```
proxy = http://ems-lnx222:8080/proxy.pac
https-proxy = http://ems-lnx222:8080/proxy.pac
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
prefix = /ws/bemccorm-rtp/npm-packages
strict-ssl = false
```

#### Update

After some more playing I figured out that the .pac proxies seemed to be causing a problem.

I used a normal proxy instead, and now get a 200 status, GET the correct tgz file, and then receive an `npm ERR! fetch failed` when trying to fetch the file.

Comment: I'm happy to give more details about the behavior if anyone can suggest more information that would be relevant.  For now I want to keep the question size manageable.

Comment: I know this is probably not at all what you want to do, but if in the very worst case scenario, you could make a private npm repository following some kind of instructions such as: http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository   and then use the --repository argument to npm to specify your behind-proxy repository.  This does of course entail keeping your private repository up-to-date with the public one, and that may be a lot more hassle than getting npm to work behind-proxy, but it is a worst-case alternative.  There are some benefits with private npm repository too.

Comment: Oh, also its: http://registry.npmjs.org/ - no dot between npm and js, which is probably where the 404 comes from unless that was just a question typo.

Comment: just a typo, I was having issues with my VNC session not letting me copy and paste out to my browser window.

Comment: I'm aware of the private repo option, but I really would rather not take that route

Comment: Is this a typo? `https-proxy = http://ems-lnx222:8080/proxy.pac`? Wouldn't you need to have an https link for your https proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it was a typo but just to make it more clear for debugging.

> When I use https, I can access with my browser, but not with wget
>
> wget https://registry.npm.js.org/yuidocjs #fails

The domain was wrong... npm.JS instead of npmjs...
Going further with wget

> wget https://registry.npmjs.org/yuidocjs
>   --2013-07-09 15:57:25--  https://registry.npmjs.org/yuidocjs
>   Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 67.228.31.146
>   Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|67.228.31.146|:443... connected.
>   ERROR: cannot verify registry.npmjs.org’s certificate, issued by “/C=US/ST=CA/L=Oakland/O=npm/OU=npm Certificate Authority/CN=npmCA/emailAddress=i@izs.me”:
>     Unable to locally verify the issuer’s authority.
>   To connect to registry.npmjs.org insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.

If  you use --no-check-certificate it works and download.

But we know this is not your MAIN problem your Main problem is the .PAC files.
I worked as a sysadmin and several times we have to write different rules at .pac files as:
1) If it is internal send everything to this router
2) If connected by vpn network do this
3) etc

So Please do a get and transcribe the .pac files so we can see the rules.
The .pac files is nothing more than javascript.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Repocache](https://github.com/pedia/repocache) worked for this.

```sh
npm config set registry https://127.0.0.1:5000/npm/default/
npm install color
```

Startup `repocache` with setting below:

```
[npm.upstream.default]
url = https://registry.npmjs.org
```

If proxy is need, add proxy like:

```
http = http://127.0.0.1:1087
https = socks5://127.0.0.1:1086
```